# Interaction with Kubuntu Irc channel crashes Quassel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubuntu, irc

I use Quassel as my irc client and have lately run into the following problem.  The Kubuntu IRC network will not connect and if ever I go into the `Configure Networks` menu to delete it, the second that I click on the Kubuntu channel, Quassel crashes.  So long as I don't go near anything that says "Kubuntu IRC," it works fine.

**Question:**  Is there a way that I can manually delete the channel manually?  Either by editing a configuration file or a database record?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't forget to submit a [bug report](http://bugs.quassel-irc.org/projects/quassel-irc/issues).

Comment: Good idea, will do.